# Synchronize different phones with one another

Tags: android, operating-system, synchronization

I have several Samsung Galaxy Tabs and I am trying to sync them with each other. For example I want  to set only one device up  and then synchronize the whole operating system (apps, os settings and filesystem) with the other devices.

Is there a easy way to share all the settings and apps from one device with the others or to make an image of the current os state and share this image with the other devices? So far I've only found solutions on how to sync something like contacs or how to share one app on different devices.

Thanks in advance.

Topper

Comment: this really isn't on topic for this site.

Comment: @slayton: thanks for the answer and I'll keep that in mind for further posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you root the devices you can use Clockwork Recovery Mod to create a Nandroid backup. You should be able to copy that file from one device to the other and then using clockwork recovery to restore the device from that backup file.

Its pretty simple to do, I've never tried using a backup from one device on another so you should probably make sure that won't cause problems.